# How to return a single field from each line in a pyspark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm sure this is very simple, but despite by trying and research I can't find the solution.  I'm working with flight info here.

I have an rdd with contents of :

```
[u'2007-09-22,9E,20363,TUL,OK,36.19,-95.88,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1745,1737,-8,1953,1934,-19', u'2004-02-12,NW,19386,DEN,CO,39.86,-104.67,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.2
2,1050,1050,0,1341,1342,1', u'2007-05-07,F9,20436,DEN,CO,39.86,-104.67,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1030,1040,10,1325,1347,22']
```

What transform do I need in order to make a new RDD with all the 2nd fields in it.

```
[u'9E',u'NW',u'F9']
```

I've tried filtering but can't make it work.  This just gives me the entire line and I only want the 2nd field from each line.

```
new_rdd = current_rdd.filter(lambda x: x.split(',')[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
data = [u'2007-09-22,9E,20363,TUL,OK,36.19,-95.88,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1745,1737,-8,1953,1934,-19', u'2004-02-12,NW,19386,DEN,CO,39.86,-104.67,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1050,1050,0,1341,1342,1', u'2007-05-07,F9,20436,DEN,CO,39.86,-104.67,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1030,1040,10,1325,1347,22']
current_rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
rdd = current_rdd.map(lambda x : x.split(',')[1])
rdd.take(10)
# [u'9E', u'NW', u'F9']
```

You are using `filter` for the wrong purpose. So let's recall the definition of the `filter` function :

> filter(f) - Return a new RDD containing only the elements that satisfy a predicate.

where as `map` returns a new RDD by applying a function to each element of this RDD, and that's what you need.

I advice to read the PythonRDD API documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD) to learn more about it.

Comment: Many thanks Eliasah.  I had looked thru the docs but I guess I just didn't understand it.

Comment: It's ok. If the functional paradigm is new to you, I suggest also reading more about it.